# How do i change a data using NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: ios5

I have an `NSMutableArray` named as `totalunits`. It has some data. Each data has value like this. `({blah blah blah},{blah = 1})`.

The second value should change to `0` instead of `1`. Thats what I explained in following codes.

```
NSMutableDictionary *inappDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [inappDict setObject:@"0" forKey:@"inapp"];
    [[totalunits objectAtIndex:currenttag] replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:newDict];
```

But using this, I'm getting an exception like this:

> [__NSCFArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: mutating method sent
>   to immutable object.

Help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've initialized your `NSMutableArray` as `NSArray`, so it has no mutation methods; double check, that you need to operation `NSMutableArray` and not `NSArray`

Comment: well, your exception description is telling another stuff =); an array that is returned by the [totalunits objectAtIndex:currenttag] is a NSArray, not a NSMutableArray - just post here a code, which adds items into the totalunits array